# How to change xml values from a excel file

Tags: python, excel, xml, pandas, numpy

I am doing a project where i need to change the values of XML tags. I need to replace them from the excel file provided to me.

I have tried to use import xml.etree.ElementTree and successfully able to change the values manually for tag UTHNMA like for eg:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for form in root.iter('UTHNMA'):
    form.text = 'id_case=12111'

tree.write('asdf1.xml', xml_declaration=True, method="xml", encoding="UTF-8")
```

I need the code of how to fetch data row wise from the excel and put it as per the tags. For eg : If the case ID is 12345 in the excel row=1, col=2, then change it.

Comment: Kindly imagine an excel file. There are headers and then data under the headers. I have to create a new xml file but just change the required values from significant cells of the excel file. I do not need to create a fresh xml, i need to do the find and replace work using python code.

Comment: Hello, I have completed my code, thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to it is :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xlrd
wb=xlrd.open_workbook
(r'C:\Users\Desktop\xml\xml.xlsx') 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

tree=ET.parse
(r'C:\Users\aniksinh\Desktop\xml\MRO57.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in 
range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(1,sheet.nrows)]

for i in range(sheet.ncols):
    UTHNMA=int(data[i][0])
    for form in root.iter(tag[0]):
        form.text = str(UTHNMA)
tree.write(r'C:\Users\Desktop\xml\new\asdf1'+'
('+str(i)+')'+'.xml', xml_declaration=True, 
method="xml", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: Finaly, got this working! Thanks so much!